# Fetching a certain text from multi-line file

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, regex-group

I would like to filter a certain text from a file using Regex package in python, taking into consideration the text file has multiple newlines and spaces. The file may have several data blocks, but the only required is the one with specific keywords. In my problem it should belong to a group contains "Route-Details" keyword.

Let us say that the file(sample.txt), is shown below.

```
.
.
.
 Host1<-->Host2 Con. ID:         0x0fc2f0d9  (abc123)
  Con. Information:
     [Gw]  Route-Details 
        R-Code:      0xaaaa (1a2) Route-Details
        Router-ID:     0x21       (a4)  [Gw] 
        Path-Code:    0x00e   (15)
        Data: 123-abcd.djsjdkks www.somesite. port 11

Coded info
                   aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa   1111-aaa
                   aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa   1111-aaa
.
.
.
```

This what I have written

```
import re
with open("sample.txt", "r") as fl:
    in_file= fl.read()

(re.search('(?<=Route-Details).* Data:', in_file,re.DOTALL).group())
```

I expect to obtain this.

```
123-abcd.djsjdkks www.somesite. port 11
```

However, I got this.

```
R-Code:      0xaaaa (1a2) Route-Details
        Router-ID:     0x21       (a4)  [Gw] 
        Path-Code:    0x00e   (15)
        Data:
```

I wonder if I can get simplified and elaborated solution(s) for this.
Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a positive look-behind and capturing group:

```
re.findall(r'(?<=Data: )(.*?)\n', text)
```

Yields:

```
['123-abcd.djsjdkks www.somesite. port 11']
```

Additionally, you can try the following to include the `Route-Details` condition you specified:

```
re.findall(r'(?<=Route-Details).*?(?<=Data: )(.*?)\n', text, re.DOTALL)
```

For a detailed explanation, see [here](https://regex101.com/r/ZeDqem/1). Also, `re.DOTALL` specifies that the `.` character will match all characters, **including newlines**.

Comment: Thanks, Can I include "Route-Details" keyword for matching?

Comment: Sure: `re.findall(r'(?<=Route-Details).*?(?<=Data: )(.*?)\n', text, re.DOTALL)`

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation. May I get explain how the matching and the escaping works?

Comment: Absolutely, I've added an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I went to the added link for explanation and I did not find the added part "Route-Details". Can you check it please? Also, can you explain the logic of the command?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

```
re.search('(?=Data: ).*\n', infile, re.DOTALL).group()
```

I think your problem is that your expression tried to match everything from 'Route-Details' to 'Data:'.

Hopefully that helps :)

Comment: Yes, since the fetched block has to have "Route-Details" keyword since there are similar groups with different keywords. Thus, I have to match whether the data related to "Route-Details". How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This will solve this problem, I have test it.
It is giving same output as you expected:

```
import re
with open("sample.txt", "r") as fl:
    in_file= fl.read()
    print(re.search('(?<=Data: ).* port 11', in_file, re.DOTALL).group())
```

Comment: This will only match when `port 11` is the specified port number. I doubt this is the desired behavior of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to retrieve part of a text with regex in python with known flanks the easiest way to do it is:

```
re.search('left_flanking_text(*.)right_flanking_text', text_to_search_into).group(1)
```

*. will match any number of characters but the newline character, so in your case, if you don't use the DOTALL flag you can use the newline character as right flank without specifying it.
The group() method without arguments (or 0 as argument) returns the full match, regardless of capturing groups.

group(1) returns the first capturing group. In your case the first capturing group is a lookbehind statement, so it would returns nothing.

Resuming the expression you need is:

```
re.search('Data:(.*)', in_file).group(1)
```

To restrict it to the Route-Details block, you can write:

```
re.search('Route-Details[\S\s]*?Data:(.*)', in_file).group(1)
```

[\S\s]* will match any character (including the new line)

?Data: will match the first 'Data:' found after the previous matchs

Comment: Thank you so much.